# Order of a group in relation to the orders of its subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose that $G$ is a finite group that has subgroups of five different orders. Prove that
>   $$|G| ≥ 12$$

I know from Lagrange's theorem that the order of a subgroup always divides the order of the group. So the product of all the orders of the subgroups must be equal to the order of the group. Using this, I know that $1, 2, 3, 4$ all divide $12$ but that's only $4$ orders, and there is no subgroup of order $0$.

Is this sufficient or where should I go next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the numbers $1$ to $11$ has $5$ distinct divisors, but $12$ has even $6$ distinct divisors. So, $12$ is the smallest possible order.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb Z_{12}$ has six subgroups with different orders, namely {$e$},  $Z_2$ , $Z_3$ , $Z_4$ , $Z_6$ and $Z_{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, that fifth subgroup will be the group itself (with order 12) when you consider the group of order 12!
So subgroups of order 1, 2, 3, 4, 12 make up the five subgroups.